# How to programmatically create a new org-roam file?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-roam

I want to create a new org-roam (v2) file (i.e., an org-roam node that is a file…) from an elisp script. I know what I want the content of that file to be, and I want the file to be created and the content to be inserted without any user interaction.

Over at org-roam's slack, someone recommended something like this to me:

```lisp
(setq org-roam-capture-templates
    `(("d" "dummy" plain "The content I want to see in the file \n%?"
                         :target (file+head "/tmp/myfile.org" "My Heading"))))
(org-roam-capture-)
```

They told me that they have something similar working, and while this is hijacking a 'private' part of org-roam (`org-roam-capture-` does not look like 'public' API), it works for them. However, if I execute this, I get this error in the debugger:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument org-roam-node nil)
  signal(wrong-type-argument (org-roam-node nil))
  org-roam-capture--target-truepath("/tmp/myfile.org")
  org-roam-capture--setup-target-location()
  org-roam-capture--prepare-buffer()
  org-capture-set-target-location(nil)
  org-capture(nil "d")
  org-roam-capture-()
  eval((org-roam-capture-) nil)
[…]
```

The problem seems to be that the symbol `org-roam-capture--node` is not set. Indeed, if you look at `org-roam-capture` (the 'public' counterpart to `org-roam-capture-`), it does:

```lisp
  (let ((node (org-roam-node-read nil filter-fn)))
    (org-roam-capture- :node node […]))
```

So apparently, `org-roam-capture-` wants to be passed an `org-roam-node` object that describes the node to capture into. However, when I change my code above to

```lisp
(setq org-roam-capture-templates
    `(("d" "dummy" plain "The content I want to see in the file \n%?"
                         :target (file+head "/tmp/myfile.org" "My Heading"))))
(org-roam-capture)
```

(note the `org-roam-capture` instead of `org-roam-capture-`), I am always prompted (via Ivy, in my case) for the node to capture into. That's also not what I want. Also I don't understand why `org-roam-capture` asks for a node when my template contains a `:target` that already specifies a node?

Is there a way of creating a new org-roam file (/node) in a given path with a given content without any user interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made something similar that might help:

```
    (defun org-roam-fast-make-link (s)
    "Make an org-roam node with title S and return a link to it.

    We eschew the usual org-capture approach for a fast, non-interactive result."
    (let* ((slug (org-roam-node-slug (org-roam-node-create :title s)))
           (filename (format "%s/%d-%s.org"
                 (expand-file-name org-roam-directory)
                 (time-convert (current-time) 'integer)
                 slug))
           (org-id-overriding-file-name filename)
           id)
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert ":PROPERTIES:\n:ID:        \n:END:\n#+title: "
            s)
        (goto-char 25)
        (setq id (org-id-get-create))
        (write-file filename)
        (org-roam-db-update-file filename)
        (format "[[id:%s][%s]]" id s))))
```

It is a bit of a hack but...

Comment: Hacky or not, works like a charm for me :)

Comment: Ok, ALMOST works. Is there an easy way to tweak the above to  return a link to an existing node, if one with the same title already exists?

Comment: Must be possible: do a search for existing nodes before embarking on the `with-temp-buffer` form.  That is an exercise for the interested reader!